# Текст из JavaScript отправить как файл локально самому себе

Tags: javascript, php, post, readfile

Попытка была такой : в JavaScript нарисовал текст, его записал в скрытый `<textarea>` на странице. Форме `<form method=post id="form_id">` отправил событие `document  . forms [ 'form_id' ] . submit  ( ) ;`. Страница обновилась и запустился процесс отправки файла.

index.php

```
  if ( ! isset (  $_SESSION [ 'flagfinishfilepingpong'  ] ) or
    $_SESSION [ 'flagfinishfilepingpong'  ] === false ) {

    if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'filename_name'  ] ) ) {
      $shifr -> filename = $_POST  [ 'filename_name'  ] ;
      unset ( $_POST [ 'filename_name'  ] ) ; }
      
    if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'boxes_info'  ] ) ) {
      $shifr -> boxes_info = $_POST  [ 'boxes_info'  ] ;
      unset ( $_POST  [ 'boxes_info'  ] ) ;
      if ( $shifr -> boxes_info ) {
        include  ( './post_file.php' ) ;
        
        exit ; } } }
```

post_file.php

```
<?php

  $_SESSION [ 'flagfinishfilepingpong'  ] = true  ;
  $_SESSION [ 'postfilefopenerror'  ] = false ;
  $_SESSION [ 'postfilefwriteerror'  ] = false  ;
  $_SESSION [ 'postfilefcloseerror'  ] = false ;
  $_SESSION [ 'postfilenotexisterror'  ]  = false ;

  $uploadfileshi = tempnam  ( "/tmp"  , "shi" ) ;
  $fpw = fopen ( $uploadfileshi , 'wb'  ) ;
  if ( $fpw === false ) {
    $_SESSION [ 'postfilefopenerror'  ] = $uploadfileshi  ;
    exit ; }
  if ( fwrite  ( $fpw , $shifr -> boxes_info ) === FALSE ) {
    $_SESSION [ 'postfilefwriteerror'  ] = $uploadfileshi  ;
    exit ;  }
  if ( fclose  ( $fpw  ) === false ) {
    $_SESSION [ 'postfilefcloseerror'  ] = $uploadfileshi  ;
    exit ;  }
  if ( file_exists ( $uploadfileshi  ) === false ) {
    $_SESSION [ 'postfilenotexisterror'  ] = $uploadfileshi ;
    exit  ; }
      
  header  ( 'Content-Description: File Transfer'  ) ;
  header  ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'  ) ;
  header  ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .
    basename ( $shifr -> filename  )  . '.shi"' ) ;
  header  ( 'Expires: 0'  ) ;
  header  ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate'  ) ;
  header  ( 'Pragma: public'  ) ;
  header  ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $uploadfileshi  ) ) ;
  readfile  ( $uploadfileshi  ) ;
  exit ;
?>
```

Отправка файла происходит пинг-понгом нормально, но останавливается страница. И на любые нажатия кнопок происходит повторная передача файла. И опять стоп и всё по-новой. Лечиться только грубым ручным перезапуском страницы.

Где ошибка? Как минимально подправить этот процесс? Какой другой способ есть для отправки файла самому себе, не используя сторонние библиотеки. Только чистый PHP и JavaScript.

Comment: После `document  . forms [ 'form_id' ] . submit  ( ) ;` происходит `POST`, запускается в `index.php` с отправкой файла в `post_file.php`. Браузер предлагает сохранить файл, и всё. Локальная страница не обновляется. @Jean-Claude

Comment: "Браузер предлагает сохранить файл, и всё" - а что ожидалось дальше?

Comment: Хотя-бы обновить страницу у клиента. @Jean-Claude

Comment: я не профи в этих делах, но обычно для скачивания файла открывают вторую страницу target=_blank потому что там файл идет потоком и обновить ту страницу никак не возможно, заголовки уже отправлены

Comment: Я уже кучу разных способов попробовал, запарился,  покажите, пожалуйста как вторую страницу создать и обновить текущую. @Jean-Claude

Comment: на jquery могу накидать пример https://pastebin.com/zG8XMQU9

Comment: С `jquery` пока ещё не дружу. Я  `jscript` только-только щупаю. @Jean-Claude

Comment: Пытаю переделать, но `$uploadfileshi = $tempnam($path, "prefix");` - имеет случайное имя. Может быть имя файла передать как `GET` ? @Jean-Claude

Comment: чистый js https://pastebin.com/hpSsa4GH

Comment: в этом и суть временного файла, не захламлять папку сайта ненужными файлами, можно создать файл просто командой fopen() в папке сайта, но после работы его надо удалить. Вообще не вижу причины создавать файл для отправки на скачивание, достаточно просто после заголовков написать echo $_POST['txt'];

Answer (score 0):

Результат отправки файла не имеет ответа от сервера. А обновление страницы не видит изменения переменных сессии `$_SESSION [ 'flagfinishfilepingpong'  ]`. И нажатие кнопки чтобы отправить файл приводит к потере связи с сервером. Решил вопрос так : убрал прямой вызов отправки файл из главной страницы. Поставил индивидуальную реакцию на разные кнопки. На простую кнопку реакция стандартная, а на специальную кнопку - вызов отправки и приёма файла без ожидания ответа. Страница **не** обновляется, но нет остановки другой работы. Вот тестовая страница, для проверки :

test_index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>EncryptTextToFile</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="id_form" >
 Filename :<br>
    <textarea name="name_filename" id="id_filename"></textarea><br>
 Text :<br>
    <textarea name="name_text" id="id_text"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Nothing" id="id_butt" >
    <input type="submit" value="Encrypt" id="id_encrypt" >
  <textarea name="name_encryptedtext" id="id_encryptedtext" readonly hidden ></textarea>
</form>

<script>
          function post_encrypt() {
        
              let text = document . getElementById ( 'id_text' ) ;
              let enctext = document . getElementById ( 'id_encryptedtext' ) ;
              enctext . value = 'Encrypted ( ' + text . value + ' )' ;
              
              document  . forms [ 'id_form' ] . action = 'test_file.php' ;
              document  . forms [ 'id_form' ] . submit  ( ) ;  } 
 
  function post_main() {
              let text = document . getElementById ( 'id_text' ) ;
              let enctext = document . getElementById ( 'id_encryptedtext' ) ;
              enctext . value = 'Другая работа ( ' + text . value + ' )' ;
              
              document  . forms [ 'id_form' ] . action = 'test_index.php' ;
              document  . forms [ 'id_form' ] . submit  ( ) ;    }
  
  let el = document.getElementById("id_butt");
  el.addEventListener("click", post_main, false);
        
      let ele = document.getElementById("id_encrypt");
      ele.addEventListener("click", post_encrypt, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test_file.php :

```
<?php

$path = sys_get_temp_dir();
$uploadfileshi = tempnam($path, "shi");
 
if(!($fpw = fopen($uploadfileshi, 'w+'))){
  exit;}
if( ! fwrite($fpw, $_POST['name_encryptedtext'])){
  exit;}
  
if(!fclose($fpw)){
  exit;}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($_POST['name_filename']) .
  '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($uploadfileshi));
 
readfile($uploadfileshi);
?>
```